# Bare or insulated grounding wire?

Tags: electrical

I am pulling about 120' 6 AWG wires from my main panel to a pool control center, and my question is do I use bare or insulated ground wire. Also, based on the tables it seems like even 10 AWG would be fine for it, but I will be using #8.

Comment: Use green insulated. I would never pull an uninsulated wire through a conduit, even if it were allowed. #14 in a PVC conduit could act like a "cheese wire" at the bends, and damage the conduit. Larger stranded wires could act like a file. And if hooked around an insulated conductor, it could cut through the insulation. In an underground conduit, moisture could cause corrosion between the copper and the steel as they are different metals. Insulated wires can be pulled with lubricant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beg pardon: insulated **is** called for, unclear why (no explanation of the "logic" is made.) http://www.biupa.com/assets/poolelectric.pdf

Comment: Oh I am not close, 3/4 would be allowed for this, I am going with 1". But I don't want to pull 120' of wire just to find out that I should have used insulated one. On one of the forums it was stated that for pool it MUST be insulated grounding wire.

Answer (score -1):

When I was working on renovation of some gas stations where there was a budget issue some design engineers claimed that there is no need to insulate wires. At the end occasionally we had to insulate them on our cost just to be on a safe side. My advice in general is that everything that is going under the surface should be protected and/or insulated.

Comment: may I please ask why di I got down vote?

Comment: My guess is that it was for the lack of an explanation. Would help to understand the "why" behind it.